# wget -O file/directory download/file Error: is no directory

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, wget

Every solution i found dont helped me. I use a Python script, the line where wget is in:

`check_call(['wget', '-O', '/home', 'download/file], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'))`

What I want to do is dowload a file and put it in a directory

Comment: I just found the error the answer here should help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23501/download-using-wget-to-a-different-directory-than-current-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify an URL. In Linux, wget works like this:

```
wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
```

It should work if you specify *args* as:

```
['wget', '-O', '/home/download/file', 'https://example.com']
```

Comment: i specified an url in my example it is "download/file"